# MySql Select where like, excluding?

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of text fields and I need to search for `#&` but I want to not include `#&39;` as almost every row has that.

Is there a way to find `#& blah blah;` and not get every `&#39;` ?

I tried doing something like

```
SELECT * FROM `content_type_mobile_event` WHERE `field_movie_desc_value` RLIKE "^(&#)";
```

But that didn't work

Comment: `#& blah blah;` or `&# blah blah;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM `content_type_mobile_event` 
   WHERE `field_movie_desc_value` 
    LIKE '&#%' 
     AND `field_movie_desc_value` 
NOT LIKE '&#39;%';
```

This will return the records whose value on the column `field_movie_desc_value` *starts* with `&#`, but does not start with `&#39;`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you simply try:

```
SELECT * FROM `content_type_mobile_event` WHERE `field_movie_desc_value` like "%#&" AND
WHERE `field_movie_desc_value` not like "#&39"
```

Comment: Double `WHERE` clauses, and the `like "%#&"` will match if the substring is at the end of the value, which is not what the OP's code does.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do a LIKE and a NOT LIKE?

```
SELECT * FROM `content_type_mobile_event` 
WHERE `field_movie_desc_value` NOT LIKE '%#&39;%' 
AND `field_movie_desc_value` LIKE '%#&'";
```

Comment: The clause `RLIKE "^(&#)"` checks if the substring is at the beginning of the value. Whereas `'%#&39;%'` will match anywhere, and `'%#&'` will match at the end of the value.